# How to create an index at the end of the book with overleaf?

Tags: indexing, makeindex, authorindex

I'm trying to make index at the end of the book after all chapters, but I couldn't get it.

I'm using the following code in main **.tex**

```
        \usepackage{imakeidx}
        \makeindex 
        \begin{document}
    %...........(call for chapters )
        \subfile{Creativity}
        \end{document}
```

and inside the chapter

```
\item \hspace{0.3 cm} \textbf{[optional]\index{optional}[story]\index{optional}[adapt]\index{adapt}[t-shaped skills]\index{t-shaped skills}[flowcharts]\index{flowcharts}}
\end{itemize}
\printindex
```

I got this index output in all chapters without the real index I really put in the code.

[image: index output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following code before the start of the document in `main.tex`

```
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, program=makeindex, options=-s pyro ,intoc=true]
```

Also by creating `pyro.ist` that contains the below code

```
heading_prefix "\n\\noindent\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
```

Comment: Interesting. How did you find out? Did you find some documentation about it?